# DocSign API - Field will not populate

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign API - I have a form with multiple dataFields.  All of the fields are populating except one.  The name of the field is tabCollege1.  Here is my request

```
    {
    "templateId": "A8A8543D-0514-48CB-9BEE-ACBADE418CA3",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabLastName",
                        "value": "Adams",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabFirstName",
                        "value": "X",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabSSN",
                        "value": "888888888",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabAddressLine1",
                        "value": "123 any st",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabApartment",
                        "value": "",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabHomePhone",
                        "value": "(502) 999-9999",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabCellPhone",
                        "value": "(502) 999-9999",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabCity",
                        "value": "Louisville",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabState",
                        "value": "KY",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabZip",
                        "value": "40214",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabEmergencyPhone",
                        "value": "(___) ___-____",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabDOB",
                        "value": "9/26/1985 12:00:00 AM",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabEmail",
                        "value": "X.adams@myata.edu",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabCompletionCredential",
                        "value": "Associates Degree",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabProgramName",
                        "value": "Medical Assisting",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabCreditHours",
                        "value": "90.00",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabStartDate",
                        "value": "1/6/2014 12:00:00 AM",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabGradDate",
                        "value": "5/23/2015 12:00:00 AM",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabNumWeeks",
                        "value": "70",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabAppFees",
                        "value": "25.00",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabTuition",
                        "value": "25380.00",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabOtherFees",
                        "value": "0.00",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabBooks",
                        "value": "3147.00",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabCollege1",
                        "value": "X Adams",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "tabPrice",
                        "value": "28552.0000",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "documentId": "1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "clientUserId": "1",
            "roleName": "Student",
            "name": "X Adams",
            "email": "hmitchell@ata.edu"
        }
    ], "status": "sent"
}
```

Can anyone see a reason why only the tabCollege1 datafield will not populate?

Thanks for your help.

ps. I attempted to post the dataField definition, but SO will not permit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have experienced behavior of tab's not populating via the API to a template, it has been related to the fact that the tab label is not what you expected. I recommend double checking the actual tab name in the template XML. You may see a guid pre-pended to the tab label if it was included as part of conditional tab logic.

Comment: Thank you Luis and Kim, both of you are correct: dataField names are case-sensitive. tabCollege1 does not match TabCollege1.

Answer (score 2):

From a syntax perspective, I don't see anything wrong with the JSON you've posted.  As to why the **tabCollege1** field is not being populated, there are at least a few possibilities that come to mind:

- The field ***name*** specified in your API request (tabCollege1) does not EXACTLY match (CASE and Spelling) the name of the field as defined in the Template.
- The field ***type*** specified in your API request (text tab) does not match with the type of the field as defined in the Template.
- The ***owner*** of the field specified in your API request (rolename=Student) does not match with the owner of the **tabCollege1** field specified in the Template.

If one of those things doesn't allow you to identify (and resolve) your issue, then I'd suggest that you update your Question with the API Response from a **GET Recipients** request:

```
https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?include_tabs=true&include_extended=false
```

Examining that response (along with your "Create Envelope" request) should enable us to identify the issue.